# rsync doesn't see/transfer any data

Tags: backup, rsync

I have a directory on remote VPS (/backuptest) with a archive in it (/backuptest/Friday.tar.gz2).

I am trying to use rsync to connect to the VPS and download the archive to my local machine (/mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS).

Each time I try to connect using my rsync command, nothing gets transferred?

```
rsync -avz -H --numeric-ids --delete -e "ssh -p ## root@{host}:/backuptest -l root" /mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS
sending incremental file list
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2013/05/17 16:47:52 VPS

sent 37 bytes  received 13 bytes  100.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

A verbose output gives:

```
rsync -avvz -H --numeric-ids --delete -e "ssh -p ## root@{host}:/backuptest -l root" /mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2013/05/17 16:54:53 VPS
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 37 bytes  received 13 bytes  100.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, turns out I hadn't closed the quotes for options before defining the source (I was mistakenly defining the source as an OPTION.

Therefore script should be:

**wrong**

```
rsync -avvz -H --numeric-ids --delete -e "ssh -p ## root@{host}:/backuptest -l root" /mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS
```

**right**

```
rsync -avvz -H --numeric-ids --delete -e "ssh -p ## -l root" "root@{host}:/backuptest" /mnt/Files_Local/backup/VPS
```